# Could not find or load main class while trying to run project from IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, classpath, apache-crunch

I have downloaded project

```
git clone http://github.com/jwills/crunch-demo
```

then imported it into IntelliJ as Maven existing project. Now I am trying to run `main` function, but failing with error message

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.WordCount
```

What is it and how to fix?

**UPDATE**

If I create new Hello World Maven project from scratch, then it works.

**UPDATE 2**

If I make any `HelloWorld` class `extends Configured implements Tool`, it also stops working:

```
public class HelloWorld extends Configured implements Tool {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }

    @Override public int run(String[] strings) throws Exception {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 3**

I need explanation from the point of view of IntelliJ: how can it loose ability to find some names in classpath just because of some class extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Configured` and `Tool` classes are not added to the classpath since the scope of the dependencies in `pom.xml` is configured as **provided**.

You are not running the class in some container that is providing these dependencies, but directly from the IDE, therefore these classes must be available in the classpath.

To fix the problem remove all the `<scope>provided</scope>` tags from `pom.xml`, **Import Changes** to update the dependencies in the Maven project.

Answer (score 0):

This may be happening because your project is not correctly opened. What do you mean you imported it into the IntelliJ? Please attach an image containing the project explorer from your opened project and I will try to help more.